# How to unfold Xception layers in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am following the official Keras transfer learning and fine-tuning tutorial. It consists of loading the Xception model with `include_top=False`, and adding a new classifier part on top.

I am then saving the model with `model.save()` and loading with `load_model()`.
So this is what I see when I do `model.summary()`

[image]

**My problem is that I would like to iterate through the layers, while now Xception layers are somehow folded (on the picture: xception(Functional)).** Is there a way to somehow unfold it, to see all the layers (including those that are creating Xception)?

Answer (score 0):

For `model. summary()`, you can unfold that as follows:

```
from tensorflow import keras 

base_model = keras.applications.Xception(
    weights='imagenet',  # Load weights pre-trained on ImageNet.
    input_shape=(150, 150, 3),
    include_top=False)  # Do not include the ImageNet classifier at the top.
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(150, 150, 3))
x = base_model(inputs, training=False)
x = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

model.summary() # full model 
model.layers[1].summary() # only xception model
```

Note, you cal also see the layer using the `plot_model` utility.

```
keras.utils.plot_model(model, expand_nested=True)
```